When is a twilio call initiated through Elastic SIP Trunking available through the API
I am using twilio Elastic SIP Trunking to connect a phone call to livekit. When the call starts livekit provides me with the callSid for the call. However, when I try to access the call via the API the call doesn't seem to exist. I have also confirmed that I cannot access the call via the dashboard while the call is ongoing. Once the call is over I can then see the call in the dashboard. Is there a way to access ongoing call initiated through Elastic SIP Trunking? is this a known issue?
